# CakePHP Database Naming Convention

Tags: sql, cakephp, naming-conventions

I had Read the CAKEPHP Convention.
So I changed from the wrong convention to the right.

However I still unsure If I name my ID correctly because now my model still need to use "$primaryKey" to override for the Delete Method.

```
Model: EventDate 
Controller: EventDatesController 
Database Table: event_dates
event_dates ID : event_date_id
```

Secondly, After I change the table col_id name , my Edit Method Query the Where clause for the primary key still remain old primary key name. Try to delete cache but still can't work.

```
SQL Query: SELECT `EventDate`.`event_date_id`, `EventDate`.`event_date`, `EventDate`.`Created`, `EventDate`.`modified` FROM `fyp_seatmanagment`.`event_dates` AS `EventDate` WHERE `EventDate`.`eventdate_id` = '65' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the naming convention for the primary key is just `id`. So your event_dates ID shout just be `id` instead of `event_date_id`.

To your second part:
You named your ID `event_date_id` but looking for `eventdate_id` in your where-clause. So you forgot a `_` there. If you change your primary key to `id`(see above) then don't to forget to fix your statement.

Answer (score 2):

Cake's naming conventions use `id` for primary keys. For foreign keys use `_id` prefixed with the singular snake cased related table name.

So for your `EventDate` model your primary key needs to be `id`.

As an example of a foreign key, if `EventData` belonged to an `Event` model then the foreign key would be `event_id`.

In your example you've confused primary and foreign keys which will cause you all sorts of headaches even if you try overriding the defaults.

You can read up more on [Cake's naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) in the docs.